# Fullscreen view from Coding4Fun Tools TimeSpanPicker shows no LoopingSelectors

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, timespan

I just added **Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll** for **TimeSpanPicker** to my project without any customization. But when I tab on my device on the control to open the full screen mode I can't see any of the 3 LoopingSelectors. It is as the 3 LoopingSelectors are not added to the page. I can only see "CHOOSE DURATION" and the Done/Cancel buttons. It is the same when I open the TimespanPickerPage.xaml in Expression Blend. It is also empty. The fullscreen mode on my device looks exaclty the same as Expression Blend: title and buttons are visible but no LoopingSelectors.

Things I've tried:

- Directly downloaded the Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll from Downloads page --> can't see any LoopingSelectors in full screen mode
- Downloaded the complete source code and compiled the dll. Added that self compiled dll --> same effect, can't see LoopingSelectors
- Added the **Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.csproj** directly to my project --> same effect, can't see LoopingSelectors

I tried to debug the TimeSpanPicker, but I'm not sure where to look for this error.

As I understand, the **TimespanPickerPage.xaml** is navigated to when opening the full screen mode. It is also calling the `InitDataSource` from TimespanPickerPage without any errors. So why can't I see any of the LoopingSelectors?

So can someone tell me where to begin to look for this bug? Or how can I fix this? I just need a simple Timespan picker in my project to let the user pick a duration.

*Side note:*

I'm also using MVVM Light Toolkit, Telerik RadControls Toolkit and Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit Feb 2011 in my project. Maybe one of these Toolkit is interfering?

*I've also opened a new discussion on Coding4Fun tools Codeplex page:* http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/discussions/254851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the Toolkit. This has been fixed at revision: 65579

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new Windows Phone Silverlight project and add a reference to `Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit`. Then you can try adding the control manually in the code-behind directly in Visual Studio:

```
Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.TimeSpanPicker picker = new Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.TimeSpanPicker();
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(picker);
```

I downloaded the package via NuGet and it worked just fine. It appears that somewhere in your project there is a control conflict.

Comment: It was a bug when using Telerik RadControls (RadPhoneApplicationFrame) together with the TimeSpanPicker.